# Exporting Event viewer Log File As A *.evtx File

Tags: c#, event-viewer

I'm trying to export information from event viewer.
I am attempting to do this with [EventLogSession](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.eventing.reader.eventlogsession(v=vs.110).aspx) so I can have it in a `.evtx` format and not just a text file.

```
public static void ExportEventViewerLog(int YearsAgo = 0, int MonthsAgo = 0, int DaysAgo = 0)
{
        int Year = 0;
        int Month = 0;
        int Day = 0;

        if (YearsAgo != 0)
        {
            Year = YearsAgo;
        }
        else if (MonthsAgo != 0)
        {
            Month = MonthsAgo;
        }
        else if (DaysAgo != 0)
        {
            Day = DaysAgo;
        }

        DateTime previousDate = DateTime.Now.AddYears(-Year).AddMonths(-Month).AddDays(-Day);
        DateTime now = DateTime.Now.Date;

        Console.WriteLine(previousDate.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"));
        //2018-06-12
        Console.WriteLine(now.ToString("hh:mm:ss"));
        //12:00:00

        string path = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop), "test.evtx");
        string query = "<QueryList> " + $@"<Select Path=""Application"">*[System[(Level=1  or Level=2 or Level=3 or Level=4 or Level=0 or Level=5) and TimeCreated[@SystemTime&gt;='{previousDate.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")}T{previousDate.ToString("hh:mm:ss")}.000Z' and @SystemTime&lt;='{now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")}T{now.ToString("hh:mm:ss")}.999Z']]]</Select> " + "</Query> " + "</QueryList>";

        EventLogSession eventLogSession = new EventLogSession();
        eventLogSession.ExportLogAndMessages("Application", PathType.LogName, query, path, false, CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);
}
```

Here is how I'm calling it

```
static void Main()
{
        ExportEventViewerLog(YearsAgo: 0, MonthsAgo: 0, DaysAgo: 1);
        Console.WriteLine("Press Any Key To Exit");
        Console.ReadKey();
}
```

Here is the error

> System.Diagnostics.Eventing.Reader.EventLogException

`System.Diagnostics.Eventing.Reader.EventLogException
  HResult=0x80131500
  Source=System.Core
  StackTrace:
   at System.Diagnostics.Eventing.Reader.EventLogException.Throw(Int32 errorCode)
   at System.Diagnostics.Eventing.Reader.NativeWrapper.EvtExportLog(EventLogHandle session, String channelPath, String query, String targetFilePath, Int32 flags)
   at System.Diagnostics.Eventing.Reader.EventLogSession.ExportLog(String path, PathType pathType, String query, String targetFilePath, Boolean tolerateQueryErrors)
   at System.Diagnostics.Eventing.Reader.EventLogSession.ExportLogAndMessages(String path, PathType pathType, String query, String targetFilePath, Boolean tolerateQueryErrors, CultureInfo targetCultureInfo)
   at app.Program.ExportEventViewerLog(Int32 YearsAgo, Int32 MonthsAgo, Int32 DaysAgo) in C:\Users\User\app\Program.cs:line 296
   atapp_1._0.Program.Main() in C:\Users\User\Google Drive\app\Program.cs:line 34`

Note: I don't believe the path is the problem because if I change the query to a wildcard `*`, the method will execute without any errors, I generated the query from `event viewer -> filter current log -> xml`
Here is the original query that was generated from Event Viewer

```
<QueryList>
<Query Id="0" Path="Application">
<Select Path="Application">*[System[(Level=1  or Level=2 or Level=3 or Level=4 or Level=0 or Level=5) and TimeCreated[@SystemTime&gt;='1991-07-24T21:12:12.000Z' and @SystemTime&lt;='2018-06-12T21:12:12.999Z']]]</Select>
```

Comment: Can you update the question with complete error message?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing the XML tag:

```
<Query Id=\"0\" Path=\"Application\">
```

Fixing this still caused that exception for me, even as admin, however using a different path fixed it (perhaps because the event viewer service lacks permissions on the users path)

```
string path = Path.Combine(Path.GetTempPath(), "test.evtx");
```

Comment: interesting, even with the path you have provided and adding the missing XML tag and as well as running vs in administrator mode, still no good, May you possible post the query you used please?

Comment: `string query = "<QueryList> <Query Id=\"0\" Path=\"Application\">" + $@"<Select Path=""Application"">*[System[(Level=1  or Level=2 or Level=3 or Level=4 or Level=0 or Level=5) and TimeCreated[@SystemTime&gt;='{previousDate.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")}T{previousDate.ToString("hh:mm:ss")}.000Z' and @SystemTime&lt;='{now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")}T{now.ToString("hh:mm:ss")}.999Z']]]</Select> " + "</Query> " + "</QueryList>";` & i used `DateTime previousDate = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1);`

Comment: You can copy the query from debug into Event Viewer & see if it accepts it.

Comment: I see, I wasn't closing the XML.